# Combination, how to compute?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

Rohit dreams he is in a shop with an infinite amount of marbles. He is allowed to select n marbles. There are marbles of k different colors. From each color there are also infinitely many marbles. Rohit wants to have at least one marble of each color, but still there are a lot of possibilities for his selection. In his effort to make a decision he wakes up. Now he asks you how many possibilities for his selection he would have had. Assume that marbles of equal color can't be distinguished, and the order of the marbles is irrelevant.

**Input**

The first line of input contains a number T <= 100 that indicates the number of test cases to follow. Each test case consists of one line containing n and k, where n is the number of marbles Rohit selects and k is the number of different colors of the marbles. You can assume that 1<=k<=n<=1000000.

**Output**
For each test case print the number of possibilities that Rohit would have had. You can assume that this number fits into a signed 64 bit integer.

**Example**

**Input**:

2

10 10

30 7

**Output:**

1

475020

So I want to ask what is the solution of the problem ? I am applying combinaiton for the following problem: (nCr) but it will give me wrong answer.

Comment: I assume this is a HackerRank challenge.

Comment: The input lines are not clear. You have to clearly state the input otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Close. $\binom{n-1}{r-1}$, Stars and Bars.

Comment: $\dbinom{n+k-1}{k-1}$  $n$ non-distinct "balls", $k$ distinct "boxes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, let Rohit select $k$ many marbles of different colors (as $k<=n$). This can be done in exactly one way. Now, we have to select $(n-k)$ marbels more. You can think of it in the following way:

Assume you have a number $r$ and you have to divide it in $i$ parts, of which one or more are allowed to be zero. This can be done in ${{r+i-1} \choose r}$ many ways. Now, this is identical to what we're trying to do. Let $r=n-k$ and $i=k$, that is all the parts correspond to a color. This can be done in ${{n-k+k-1} \choose {n-k}}={{n-1} \choose {n-k}}={{n-1} \choose {k-1}}$ many ways. This gives correct results to the test case you've given. So, I believe we're right.

**EDIT:** As @Vikas requested, I'm including the proof of the formula that I used. By the way, this is called the "Stars and baes" theorem. Here, we'll see in how many ways we can divide $r$ in $n$ parts. Let's use an analogy. There are $r$ identical balls. Partitioning the balls would be similar to what we are trying to achieve. To do so, let us take $(n-1)$ sticks. We arrange the balls and sticks linearly. The number of balls in between two sticks would be the parts that we seek. Exempli gratia:
$$**|***||**$$ would represent $2+3+0+2=7$. This can be done in $\frac{(r+n-1)!}{r! (n-1)!}$ ways (as there are $r$ identical balls and $(n-1)$ identical sticks). This is the same as ${{n+r-1}\choose r}$.

Comment: ${{r+i-1} \choose r}$ many ways, can you please describe this

Comment: @Vikas Check out my edit.